# How can I use DISTINCT and VALUE in same query?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to get an array of only the values from the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Section
FROM c
WHERE c.brand = 'monki'
AND c.Consumer = 'Storelens_V2'
```

So I changed it to this

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.Section
FROM c
WHERE c.brand = 'monki'
AND c.Consumer = 'Storelens_V2'
```

but this gives the error

```
Failed to query item for container formatteddata:
 Cannot set property 'headers' of undefined
```

How can I use distinct and Value at the same time?

Comment: By "only the values" what exactly do you mean?  What was wrong with your first attempt and what are you expecting as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As weird as this is, by filtering out null values this query works, I really dont understand why but simply adding a where clause where distinct_property != null solves the problem directly

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE(c.Section)
FROM c
WHERE c.brand = 'monki'
AND c.Consumer = 'Storelens_V2'
```

Comment: Great answer, and would be even greater with an explanation regarding how this solves the problem (and maybe even a bit of sample output). Just general feedback, when posting an answer that just contains code.

Comment: This does not work, it gives the same error as I posted in the query